# Java JSON subobject

Tags: java, json

Can anyone explain me how to correctly insert a subobject into JSONObject? I've tried both implementations - `org.json.simple` and `org.json` and code like:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("key", "value");
obj.put("subobject", obj.toString());
```

After these strings I except:

```
{"key":"value","subobject":{"key":"value"}}
```

But actual value is:

```
{\"key\":\"value\","subobject":{"key":"value"}}
```

It always escapes the quotes while inserting JSONObject so I can't do it correctly. Of course I can try to modify the code but I wonder - really, nobody asked that before? So I guess the solution is right in front of me but I can't just see it. Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONObject subobj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("key", "value");
obj.put("subobject", subobj);
```

without the `toString()`

Also, the way you print the JSONObject affects how it is displayed. Do you use `System.out`? or the debugger? As long as you can parse the result string again into a JSONObject, there is no real problem, right?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy see edited answer. But now I get it: you're trying to add the _same_ object to your object. Why?

Comment: Oh, yes, I've already realized and removed the comment. Okay, gonna try it soon, but I bet this is a solution. One advice for others - get some sleep before coding :)